# Infinite loops? For what case do these loops occur?

Tags: scala, debugging, infinite-loop

I have submitted my scala assignment on coursera however it seems that some of the tests failed:

```
  Your solution achieved a testing score of 70 out of 110.
Below you can see a short feedback for every test that failed, indicating the reason
for the test failure and how many points you lost for each individual test.

[Test Description] filter: tweet with 321 retweets
[Observed Error] Test timeout: aborted after 40 seconds; Check for infinite loops!
  [exception was thrown] detailed error message in debug output section below
[Lost Points] 10

[Test Description] filter and union: tweets with 321 and 205 retweets
[Observed Error] Test timeout: aborted after 40 seconds; Check for infinite loops!
  [exception was thrown] detailed error message in debug output section below
[Lost Points] 10

[Test Description] filter and trending: tweets with 321 and 205 retweets
[Observed Error] Test timeout: aborted after 40 seconds; Check for infinite loops!
  [exception was thrown] detailed error message in debug output section below
[Lost Points] 10

[Test Description] trending: google and apple tweets
[Observed Error] Test timeout: aborted after 40 seconds; Check for infinite loops!
  [exception was thrown] detailed error message in debug output section below
[Lost Points] 10
```

My problem is that I cannot imagine any cases that my functions fail. The standard tests offered through the assignment run without a problem.

Here is the filter and union function:

```
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = (left.union(right)).union(that).incl(elem)
  val isEmpty = false

  def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = filterAcc(p,new Empty)

  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    if(left.isEmpty && right.isEmpty) acc
    else if(p(elem)){ left.filterAcc(p,acc.incl(elem)).union(right.filterAcc(p,acc.incl(elem)))}
    else left.filterAcc(p,acc).union(right.filterAcc(p,acc))


  }
```

Here is the full code if anybody needs it for better debugging:

```
  package objsets

import common._
import TweetReader._

/**
 * A class to represent tweets.
 */
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" +
    "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]"
}

/**
 * This represents a set of objects of type `Tweet` in the form of a binary search
 * tree. Every branch in the tree has two children (two `TweetSet`s). There is an
 * invariant which always holds: for every branch `b`, all elements in the left
 * subtree are smaller than the tweet at `b`. The eleemnts in the right subtree are
 * larger.
 *
 * Note that the above structure requires us to be able to compare two tweets (we
 * need to be able to say which of two tweets is larger, or if they are equal). In
 * this implementation, the equality / order of tweets is based on the tweet's text
 * (see `def incl`). Hence, a `TweetSet` could not contain two tweets with the same
 * text from different users.
 *
 *
 * The advantage of representing sets as binary search trees is that the elements
 * of the set can be found quickly. If you want to learn more you can take a look
 * at the Wikipedia page [1], but this is not necessary in order to solve this
 * assignment.
 * 
 * [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
 */
abstract class TweetSet {

  def greatestCurrent(soFar: Tweet):Tweet

  def iterateAndAddList(list: TweetList): TweetList

  def isEmpty: Boolean
  /**
   * This method takes a predicate and returns a subset of all the elements
   * in the original set for which the predicate is true.
   *
   * Question: Can we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
  def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet

  /**
   * This is a helper method for `filter` that propagetes the accumulated tweets.
   */
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` that is the union of `TweetSet`s `this` and `that`.
   *
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
   def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet;

  /**
   * Returns the tweet from this set which has the greatest retweet count.
   *
   * Calling `mostRetweeted` on an empty set should throw an exception of
   * type `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
   *
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
  def mostRetweeted: Tweet = ???

  /**
   * Returns a list containing all tweets of this set, sorted by retweet count
   * in descending order. In other words, the head of the resulting list should
   * have the highest retweet count.
   *
   * Hint: the method `remove` on TweetSet will be very useful.
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
  def descendingByRetweet: TweetList


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` which contains all elements of this set, and the
   * the new element `tweet` in case it does not already exist in this set.
   *
   * If `this.contains(tweet)`, the current set is returned.
   */
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` which excludes `tweet`.
   */
  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Tests if `tweet` exists in this `TweetSet`.
   */
  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean

  /**
   * This method takes a function and applies it to every element in the set.
   */
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit
}

class Empty extends TweetSet {
  def greatestCurrent(soFar: Tweet):Tweet = new Tweet("a","b",-1)
  def iterateAndAddList(list: TweetList): TweetList = list
  def descendingByRetweet() = Nil
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that  
  def isEmpty = true

  def filter(p: Tweet=> Boolean): TweetSet = new Empty()

  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = new Empty()


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean = false

  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = new NonEmpty(tweet, new Empty, new Empty)

  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = this

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = ()
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

  def descendingByRetweet = {






    iterateAndAddList(Nil)

  }

      def iterateAndAddList(list: TweetList): TweetList = {

      val current: Tweet = greatestCurrent(new Tweet("a","b",-1))
      if(current.retweets != -1){
      this.remove(current).iterateAndAddList(list.add(current))
      }else list

    }

    def greatestCurrent(soFar: Tweet):Tweet = {
      if(left.isEmpty && right.isEmpty) soFar
      else{
          if(elem.retweets < soFar.retweets) { mostPopular(left.greatestCurrent(soFar),right.greatestCurrent(soFar))     }
          else if(elem.retweets > soFar.retweets){ mostPopular(left.greatestCurrent(elem),right.greatestCurrent(elem))   }
          else { mostPopular(left.greatestCurrent(soFar),right.greatestCurrent(soFar))   }
      }
    }

    def mostPopular(left: Tweet,right: Tweet):Tweet = {
      if(left.retweets > right.retweets) left
      else if(right.retweets > left.retweets) right
      else left
    }

  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = (left.union(right)).union(that).incl(elem)
  val isEmpty = false

  def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = filterAcc(p,new Empty)

  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    if(left.isEmpty && right.isEmpty) acc
    else if(p(elem)){ left.filterAcc(p,acc.incl(elem)).union(right.filterAcc(p,acc.incl(elem)))}
    else left.filterAcc(p,acc).union(right.filterAcc(p,acc))


  }


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(x: Tweet): Boolean =
    if (x.text < elem.text) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) right.contains(x)
    else true

  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
  }

  def remove(tw: Tweet): TweetSet =
    if (tw.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.remove(tw), right)
    else if (elem.text < tw.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.remove(tw))
    else left.union(right)

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = {
    f(elem)
    left.foreach(f)
    right.foreach(f)
  }
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why my code fails? I'm not looking for baked code as this would violate the coursera honour code. I would appreciate any feedback regarding to what is wrong with my code.

Note: The standard tests supplied with the assignment run fine. The problem is when submitting. Also do not give me baked code please

Comment: Your union function is too slow (not infinite); try another way to implement it. p.s. try to use `filterAcc`

Comment: I can submit 3 more times. Are you sure this is right? It's just a call which should last no more than 0.000001 seconds

Comment: One general suggestion: Since your data-structure is immutable, you can declare `Empty` as an `object`. This prevents the creation of many `Empty`-Objects which basically have the exact same information and behavior.

Comment: Yes I made this task more than a year ago; so had same problems... But there were no such questions here; 
I made the same `union` function as u, but it was very slow; this function is a very very ... very slow, try another variant.

Comment: This issue has been extensively discussed on the Coursera forums. I'm not sure why you see the need to post your code here, especially -- as others have already pointed out - it is a clear violation of the honor code?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of union is too inefficient. It can easily be refactored to be more efficient. It can still just use recursive calls to union and the incl method but not in the order that you have.

I suspect is not a truely infinite loop, but instead just runs too long for the Coursera tests. That is why your local, smaller test cases pass.

Comment: @Bula - btw, the Coursera honor code requires that you do not share your solutions with others. Posting all your code here might be considered against the honor code. I might be wrong but if you'd like to ensure you are within the honor code, why not copy and post this exact question on the course forum on Coursera? I am sure your'll get feedback on the your issue as well as an indication if this is against the honor code. http://help.coursera.org/customer/portal/articles/1164381-what-is-the-honor-code-